# (Complex sentence) Using the word "and" right before a subordinate conjunction

Tags: grammar, complex-sentences

I have a few questions about complex sentence

Here are the examples:
Because I had to catch the train, **and** as we were short on time, I forgot to pack my toothbrush for our vacation.

I gave strength to her **and** that enabled her to perform better.

Which in parts of speech is the word "and" ? 
Can we use "and" right before a relative pronoun or subordinating conjuction?
What is the purpose of adding the word "and"?

Thanks!

The sources of the examples given above:
http://examples.yourdictionary.com/complex-sentence-examples.html
https://www.csgenerator.com/complex-sentence-examples

Comment: I would dispute whether the second example is complex - it looks like a compound sentence (two independent clauses), with "and" as the coordinating conjunction.

Comment: How about  "that enabled her to perform better" ?,  it looks like a dependent clause to me.  It will sound strange without the independent clause.